# Yii2 проблема с отображением страницы

Tags: php, yii2, nginx

Помогите решить вопрос с отображением страницы, не могу понять в чем проблема. Иногда страница отображается в таком формате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше такой проблемы не было до включения gzip.
А также изменения формата css-files.css.gzip и js-files.css.gzip

Comment: а формат там укзали что utf-8

Comment: не могли бы уточнить конкретнее что Вы имеете ввиду?